# Increment AlphaNumeric in VB.NET form Textbox

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to generate an auto increment alphabumeric ID in a textbox on form load, and with the below code, and I can insert the first set of data to ID "ABC1" to an empty table, but on next load, The system will throw an error saying Conversion from string "ABC1" to type double is not not valid.

Can I have some help on the code please.

Thanks.

```
Try

    Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection()
        con.Open()
        Dim myCommand As SqlCommand
        Dim pdid As String
        myCommand = New SqlCommand("select ISNULL(Max(ID),0) From SQLTable", con)
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader
        reader.Read()
        id= reader.Item(0) + 1
        pdidbox.Text = "ABC" + pdid.ToString()
        reader.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: is the format fix? 3 letters with 1 number?

Comment: Hello, Yes it can be fix format..  Thanks.

Comment: what if the last value is `ABC9`? will the next is `ABC10`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code you will get a formatted string that could be correctly retrieved from your database using the MAX function

```
Dim curValue as Integer
Dim result as String
using con as SqlConnection = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;initial catalog=TEMPDB;Trusted_Connection=True;")
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd  = new SqlCommand("Select MAX(ID) FROM TEST", con)
    result = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()
    if string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) Then
        result = "ABC000"
    End If

    result = result.Substring(3)
    Int32.TryParse(result, curValue)
    curValue = curValue  + 1
    result = "ABC" + curValue.ToString("D3")

End Using
```

This code will store in the ID column strings formatted as 'ABC001', 'ABC002' and so on. The inclusion of zeros before the number stored is required by the MAX function if you try to use it on string values otherwise a string ABC2 will be higher than ABC19 because the comparison of the 4th character.
Of course when you query a datatable to search for a single result like above is simpler to use ExecuteScalar than using a datareader.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    Public Function IncrementString(ByVal Sender As String) As String
    Dim Index As Integer
    For Item As Integer = Sender.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
        Select Case Sender.Substring(Item, 1)
            Case "000" To "999"
            Case Else
                Index = Item
                Exit For
        End Select
    Next
    If Index = Sender.Length - 1 Then
        Return Sender & "1" '  Optionally throw an exception ?
    Else
        Dim x As Integer = Index + 1
        Dim value As Integer = Integer.Parse(Sender.Substring(x)) + 1
        Return Sender.Substring(0, x) & value.ToString()
    End If
End Function
```

Then call it as shown:

```
Dim comm As New SqlCommand
 comm.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(UserID) FROM SQLTable"
```