# Increment the sql ID column and put value in Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am having trouble getting the SQL ID (not an auto increment) to increment and then having that value (alphanumaric) populate a textbox.
I have followed [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17744238/increment-column-value-in-database-using-c-sharp-asp-net) for the increment and [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16565035/how-do-i-get-values-from-a-sql-database-into-textboxes-using-c) for populating the value to the textbox.  I do not see the ID being Incremented and my textbox is still empty.

Can some one please tell me what I am doing wrong.

This is the code I am having problems with:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, Eventargs e)
    {
        string ID_upd = "UPDATE table SET ID = ID + 1";
        string ID_sel = "SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM table ORDER BY ID DESC";

        SqlConnection IDcon = new SqlConnection(Connection string);
        SqlCommand cmdupd = new SqlCommand(ID_upd, IDcon);
        SqlCommand cmdsel = new SqlCommand(ID_sel, IDcon);

        IDcon.Open();
        cmdupd.ExecuteNonquery();
        IDcon.Close();

        try
        {
            IDcon.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader read = cmdsel.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (read.Read())
                {
                TextboxID.Text = (read["ID"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            IDcon.close();
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the help.

Edit:  I have ran this in my test page.  I was successful in populating the textbox but not the update commmand.  error received is: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'A12345' to data type int.  Also this is not my last ID value.

Comment: Have you used the debugger? Do you really want to update _all_ rows?

Comment: It is wrong approach, between this two SQL commands the ID can be changed.

Comment: Tim,  I will try that. thanks        Hamlet,  I need the ID updated to the next incrament and then put the new ID value in the Textbox.  should I seperate out the commands and just have the load page go the each one seperatly?

Comment: Firstly, your update statement is updating every single row in the table, I highly doubt that's what you're meaning to do. Secondly, try setting a break point and seeing what values are being returned.

Comment: Ben,  you are right, I only want to update the ID column, but from what I read that update command should only update the ID column.  Am I missreading the post?

Comment: @user3549282: you're updating only the id-column but in every row in the table since you haven't specified a  `Where`-clause. For example: `UPDATE table SET ID = ID + 1 WHERE ID = @OldID`. However, this and the following `SELECT` are race conditions with multiple users which are updating parallel. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Tim is right, you want to use a `WHERE` clause, so you only update one record, instead of every single one. Also, why are you running the update in the first place? From what I can see in your code you're only just wanting to get the max ID of the column and then add 1 to it, correct? Or is there code we don't see?

Comment: That is correct.  I have several tables to update is data and they all referance this ID column.  some tables have more than 2 record for this ID and others only have the one.

Comment: Okay, you definitely don't want to update all of them then, since that essentially deletes any ties you have to that record in other tables. Also, to get the highest value in the ID column a simple `SELECT MAX(ID) FROM table` will do the trick. No need for an update. Try changing that and using only the one statement, then debug and see what the value is.

Comment: @Tim,  I am trying to debug my full formated page and my test page and see the difference and why my full page doesn't work.

Comment: @Ben, thank you I will work with that.  That should make it take the last ID.

Comment: Just checking in, did you get this resolved?

Comment: @Ben,  Not yet.  I am still having problems with the increment.  I found a couple of sites that I am trying for the increment.  [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1735515.aspx?ASP+NET+AND+C+HOW+CAN+I+MAKE+AUTO+INCREMENT+NUMBER+) and [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/thread/218080/auto-increment-of-alphanumeric-number-using-C-Sharp.aspx)  Thanks for checking

Comment: @BenBlack I have it working on my test page.  Now on the other page.  I will update the code in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I found to get the last ID value and get it to increment.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, Eventargs e)
    {
        string ID_sel = "SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM table ORDER BY ID DESC";

        SqlConnection IDcon = new SqlConnection(Connection string);
        SqlCommand cmdsel = new SqlCommand(ID_sel, IDcon);

        IDcon.Open();
        SqlDataReader read = cmdsel.ExecuteReader();

        read.Read();
        string a = read["ID"].ToString();

        TextboxID.Text = ();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            string val = a.Substring(1, a.Length - 1);
            int newnumber = Convert.ToInt32(val) + 1;
            a = "B" + newnumber.ToString("000000");
        {
        TextBoxID.Text = a;
        IDcon.Close;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a syntax meant for numbers to 'increment' an alphanumeric string and that's why you are getting the error on update.

You cannot do that this way.

I would go with a stored procedure instead.

As a last resort that to me is pure evil are 3 statements:

1- Select to get the highest id

2- C# to split & increment the numeric part and then assemble the ID

3- Sql statement to update

But you can be sure you will run into issues when online because this solution will  not handle gracefully concurrency...

I strongly suggest a stored procedure

i think also that your sql is missing a `WHERE` clause in the `UPDATE` statement: are you sure you want to overwrite each and every row in the table?

Comment: [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038372/increment-alphanumeric-in-vb-net-form-textbox) is the first i found. you can modify it to suit your needs. once again i would go for a stored procedure instead.

Comment: I added the code after I converted it to C#, but I am not seeing the reason for the error.

Comment: @user3549282 i think you are making a mess... in my answer i refer to the error in you **original code**: 'UPDATE table SET ID = ID + 1' can't work because you are adding a string to an integer and that's why you get an error with your **original code**. now you mention an error in your **newly added** c# code without any info about this new and unknown error... you have an error with your new c# code?